# batch file restart or close running programs with time with no warning message

Tags: windows, batch-file

i'm working with batch file right now, I am trying to run a batch file that will restart or close a program with a given time with no warning message(for restart). is this possible? i know how to restart using a batch file but i can't find a way to hide or not show the warning message. tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Taskkill /?

taskkill /f /im notepad.exe
```

Comment: does it have an option like /t ? i need to set a timer

Comment: tnx for the reply dude.